# Dovecot Object Storage Plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, dovecot, mta, s3fs

I know this isn't a very technical question; but where can I find the high-latency object storage addon for amazon s3? The official Open-Xchange site link gives a 404 to the 'Dovecot Store'.

I've been restlessly trying to have this done for quite few months to no avail, even emailed dovecot co-founder Mikko Linnamäki who told my project isn't big enough, and to ask the "open source community".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to download the object storage plugin, you're out of luck as it's a commercial plugin that only works with the commercial dovecot pro.

http://www.dovecot.fi/products/

> Optimized usage of Dovecot with Cloud technologies, such as Windows Azure, Amazon S3, Scality and Dropbox.
>
> The Dovecot Object Storage Plugin enables your Dovecot email service to store the email data into a Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

1. https://github.com/s3ql/main end Maildir
2. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse end Maildir

About S3QL
S3QL is a file system that stores all its data online using storage services like Google Storage, Amazon S3, or OpenStack. S3QL effectively provides a hard disk of dynamic, infinite capacity that can be accessed from any computer with internet access.

S3QL is a standard conforming, full featured UNIX file system that is conceptually indistinguishable from any local file system. Furthermore, S3QL has additional features like compression, encryption, data de-duplication, immutable trees and snapshotting which make it especially suitable for online backup and archival.

S3QL is designed to favor simplicity and elegance over performance and feature-creep. Care has been taken to make the source code as readable and serviceable as possible. Solid error detection and error handling have been included from the very first line, and S3QL comes with extensive automated test cases for all its components.

Comment: I know about s3 files systems, but they don't play very nice with an unsuspecting mta like dovecot which takes simple file store attributes like 'date created' very seriously. Moreover s3 itself mangles those metadata thoroughly.